# 404 for Wordpress Tag Functionality?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, robots.txt

Every time I add a tag google webmaster tools creates a 404 error for the tag based on the following path

EG:

```
tag/<tag name1>/contact
tag/<tag name2>/contact
```

I have the following disallow i my robots.txt file

```
Disallow: /tag/
```

Why do I get this error?

Is there a way to exlude these in .htaccess maybe a redirect or is there a way to resolve the 404?

It seems strange that the Disallow doesn't stop google from trying to index it?

Site: www.simonjohn.co.uk

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the tags are listed in your sitemap here: http://simonjohn.co.uk/post_tag-sitemap.xml which Google probably gives higher precedence than robots.txt

I'm pretty sure the Yoast plugin you're using has an option to disable the indexing of tags, look in the options page.